# Can we run specific steps of a Test-Case in Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework

I am using Robot Framework and I was wondering if it possible to run only particular steps within a test-case. For example, if I want to do a test in which, I just input the username and Submit, will I have to write a different test-case or can I conditionally run the test-case listed below ?

In other words, can Invalid Login(Testcase listed below) take parameters and execute only specific steps. For example, run Input Username and Submit or Run Input Password and Submit or Run both of these and then submit.

```
*** Test Cases ***
Invalid Login
  Open Browser To Login Page
  Input Username    demo
  Input Password    check
  Submit Credentials
  Login Should Have Failed
  [Teardown]    Close Browser
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, the best approach is to have separate tests.

If you insist on having a test case with optional steps, the way I would do this is to put the optional parts in one or more keywords, and then use `Run Keyword If` to conditionally exclude a step.

For example:

```
*** Keywords ***
| Do additional validation
| | log | doing additional validation...

*** Test Cases ***
| Invalid Login
| | Open Browser To Login Page
| | Input Username | demo
| | Input Password | check
| | Submit Credentials
| | Login Should Have Failed
| | # run the following only if "${DO_MORE}" is defined
| | Run keyword if | ${DO_MORE} == True
| | ... | Do additional validation
| | [Teardown] | Close Browser
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look into how to write data driven tests for Robot Framework. A good example is provided with Robot Framework:

https://bitbucket.org/robotframework/webdemo/wiki/Home#rst-header-test-cases

Answer (score 0):

What we did is to use the TAGS in the test name. And then when you run the command you can use the option -i or -e (include or exclude) the specific tags that you want to run or not run.
So in your case:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Invalid Login
  Open Browser To Login Page
  [Tags]    specific_tags
  Input Username    demo
  [Tags]    specific_tags
  Input Password    check
  Submit Credentials
  [Tags]    specific_tags
  Login Should Have Failed
  [Teardown]    Close Browser
```

And then you run with the command:
`robot -i specific_tags your_robot_file.robot`
Hope it can help someone even the question is quite old